# Task was cancelled PostAsync C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

```
protected HttpResponseMessage SendJsonRequest(HttpClient client, string jsonRequest)
    {
        var mediaType = "application/json";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(mediaType));

        return client.PostAsync(ApiUrl, new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType)).Result;
    }
```

The error is that the task was cancelled, can it be related with the Api or will be from my code?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text; just post the text. We can read the "A task was canceled." within.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (and much easier if, say, we have set our font size larger in our browsers...)

Comment: Did you change the `Timeout` settings of your `HttpClient` from default?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't await the `PostAsync`. Change the method as below and change the invocation to `await SendJsonRequest(...)`

```
protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendJsonRequest(HttpClient client, string jsonRequest)
{
    var mediaType = "application/json";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(mediaType));

    return await client.PostAsync(ApiUrl, new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType));
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet `await client.PostAsync(...)).Result` << don't call `.Result` and `await` it at the same time

Comment: @PeterCsala Artifact from fixing OPs code. Fixed.